# How to fix List index out of range in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, qlistwidget

I have a code that displays items (files) in a QlistWidget where the user clicks on the item and the system displays its content.

The Problem is when the user clicks on the item the system crashes and displays the below error:

> File
>   "c:\Users\test\Documents\Python_Projects\tests_scripts\qt_creator\Python_Projects-AnthonyKifawi-\myPDFviewer.py",
>   line 159, in FileListSelected   Item= oneDir + "\" +
>   self.listWidgetPDFlist.selectedItems()[index].text()
>
> builtins.IndexError: list index out of range

existing files in the list :

- C:\Users\test\Desktop\New Microsoft Word Document.docx ==> row 0
- C:\Users\test\Desktop\test_arabic.docx ==> row 1

displayed Result :

> this is P==>C:\Users\test\Desktop\test_arabic.docx
>     this is
>   oneDir==>C:\Users\test
>    this is the cuurent Item
>   ==C:\Users\test\Desktop\test_arabic.docx
>   this is ppp==>C:\Users\test\Desktop\test_arabic.docx current row = 1

this is

> P==>C:\Users\test\Desktop\test_arabic.docx
>   this is
>   oneDir==>C:\Users\test
>    this is the cuurent Item
>   ==C:\Users\test\Desktop\test_arabic.docx this is ppp==>C:\Users\test\Desktop\test_arabic.docx current row = 0

## code:

```
def FileListSelected(self):             # Function to select the desired file from the list in the left pane
        ListIterator=range(self.listWidgetPDFlist.count())

        for index in ListIterator:
            p = pathlib.Path(self.fullPath)
            print("this is P==>{}".format(p))
            oneDir = os.path.join(*p.parts[:-2])
            print("this is oneDir==>{}".format(oneDir))            
            Item= oneDir + "\\" + self.listWidgetPDFlist.selectedItems()[index].text()
            print("this is the cuurent Item =={}".format(Item))            
            ppp=os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), Item) 
            print("this is ppp==>{}".format(ppp))
            self.mouseHover()

            return ppp
```

Comment: You are iterating over all the items but only indexing into the selected items. Why don't you just iterate over the selected items directly, e.g.: `for item in self.listWidgetPDFlist.selectedItems():`

Comment: i tried your answer and the system display this error :

**File "c:\Users\test\Documents\Python_Projects\tests_scripts\qt_creator\Python_Projects-AnthonyKifawi-\myPDFviewer.py", line 162, in FileListSelected
  Item= oneDir + "\\" + self.listWidgetPDFlist.selectedItems()[index].text()

builtins.TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not QListWidgetItem**

Comment: When you iterate over the items you don't need `self.listWidgetPDFlist.selectedItems()[index].text()` - just `item.text()`.

Comment: still having a problem  ---Now  when i try to select one of 2 files the result display is the same file in different row count--- i will edit my question and add an  Example